# Получение input.value из footer balloon перед закрытием

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Есть точка

```
new ymaps.GeoObject({ geometry: geometry, properties: properties }, options);
```

с кастомным футером:

```
let properties = {
  ...
  balloonContentFooter: '<input.../>'
};
```

Точка добавляется через:

```
let clusterer = new ymaps.Clusterer(options)
clusterer.add(points)
ymap.geoObjects.add(clusterer)
```

Как при закрытии/перед закрытием balloon прочитать данные input из футера?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

инпуту можно назначить уникальный идентификатор и достучатся до него простым селектом:

```
balloonContentFooter: '<input id="myinput" value=10>'
```

Для того чтобы получить содержимое метки перед закрытием можно использовать событие 'beforeuserclose':

```
myPlacemark.balloon.events.add('beforeuserclose', function () {
    console.log(window.myinput.value)
})
```